How to hide all block Schemas from Swagger in ApiPlatform?
I want to hide block Schemas in Swagger generated by ApiPlatform
Any ideas?
Overriden vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Resources/views/SwaggerUi/index.html.twig
Is very difficult, because it generate content from js

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
